# Adding a console window to an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: console-application, asp.net-core-2.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.0 application running on windows in .NET Core 2.0:

[image]

Commandline:

> "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" exec "C:\Users\zippy\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\WebApplication4\WebApplication4\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\WebApplication4.dll"

How do I make it appear in a console window?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was actually launching the code in IIS Express, I just didn't realize it. You have to select the profile in the drop down play button in Visual Studio

[image: IIS Play button setting]

Then the console app launches:

[image: Console window]