# NLog Console Window Not Opening

Tags: nlog, visual-studio-2022

I've been using NLog for about 8 months and I absolutely love it! I maintain a dozen or so REST APIs that I manage with Visual Studio. Whenever I run the application from VS, Swagger opens up in my browser and the logs pop up in a console window and I can watch the logs display in real time as I test and debug. It has always worked perfectly, but since upgrading to VS2022, the console window no longer opens, so I can't see the logs. Is there a config value in NLOG or an environment setting in Visual Studio I need to change?

Here is my config file if it helps.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="">

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
            
    <target xsi:type="Console" name="ConsoleLog" detectConsoleAvailable="false"
            layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ConsoleLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652375/adding-a-console-window-to-an-asp-net-core-application ?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56344959/asp-net-core-app-output-in-a-console-window ?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148660/how-to-get-a-console-output-in-asp-net-core-with-iis-express ?